# Scala implicit conversion from parent trait

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, traits

The following code does not compile:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

trait Base {
  class Wrp[+T](val v: T) // wrapper / internal representation
}

trait BooleanOps extends Base {
  // implicit conversion
  implicit def lift2BooleanOpsCls(x: Boolean): BooleanOpsCls =
    new BooleanOpsCls(new Wrp[Boolean](x))
  class BooleanOpsCls(wx: Wrp[Boolean]) {
    def ||(wy: =>Wrp[Boolean]): Wrp[Boolean] = new Wrp[Boolean](wx.v || wy.v)
  }
}

trait MyExample extends BooleanOps {
  // test method
  def foo(): Wrp[Boolean] = {
    val ret: Wrp[Boolean] = false || new Wrp[Boolean](true)
    ret
  }
}
```

Output:

```
MyExample.scala:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : MyExample.this.Wrp[Boolean]
 required: Boolean
        val ret: Wrp[Boolean] = false || new Wrp[Boolean](true)
                                         ^
```

But if I:

1) put the `class Wrp` outside of Base

or

2) move the body of `BooleanOps` to `MyExample`

everything compiles.

Why does not the original example work? If you have some insight in this behavior, help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

One issue is the call-by-name nature of the argument in the `def ||(wy: =>Wrp[Boolean])`
if you rewite it to `def ||(wy: Wrp[Boolean])` it works

but I agree that it is weird that it works if you move around Wrp or BooleanOpsCls! Intended or bug of implicit resolution??

Comment: Great, I can confirm that this works. Thanks :)
The question remains what is exactly happening in the original example, also relating to the two workarounds proposed.

Comment: @perovic Just the idea in context of @cbastin answer: I assume that because of the nature of call-by-name argument implicit search is done differently, because `=>Wrp[Boolean]` is a block of code rather than type. Because of that compiler doesn't consider this method definition is applicable during implicit search. Unfortunately I cannot confirm this with any reliable source, so it is a completely wild guess. But given that the behavior is weird and depends on `Wrp` positioning, it looks like a bug, and I guess it's worth posting it as a jira ticket for compiler team?

Comment: @Archeg Thank you for the advice. It seems that many elements and rules are interacting. I am still unsure this is a bug, so I will wait a bit more in hope someone will be able to give a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The original example will work if you rename the `||` method.  The compiler finds the `false.||()` method and doesn't bother to look for an implicit that might also work there.

Comment: Indeed, this works, but I am trying to overload `||` operator behavior.
The compiler finds the method with the same name (`||`), but the argument type is different (`Wrp[Boolean]` instead of `Boolean`), so it should perform implicit search. This indeed happens if I put the implicit conversion in the body of `MyExample` or if I put the `class Wrp` definition outside of `Base`, as specified in the question. I do not understand why these solutions work and the original example does not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no single class called `Wrp` (ignore the `T` for a moment) -- `Base` does not define `Wrp` but rather defines a named subclass of each and every *concrete* class that extends `Base`. The implicits are a red herring, too. The error that's the giveaway is the mention of `MyExample.this.Wrp` -- remember that there is no such class even as `MyExample` -- `val x = new MyExample` would have type `Object with MyExample`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Rob. In the actual code `Wrp` is an abstract type, I have simplified it here. But still the example works if the `Wrp[Boolean]` argument of the `||` operator is call-by-value or if I put the implicit conversion (both the `implicit def` and the `class`) inside MyExample trait. Do you know how does this relate to your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure... maybe you could add an additional, alternative minimal example?